# PowerShell RegEx pattern matching for Mobile / Cell phone in AD?

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

What's the Powershell RegEx pattern that match the below pattern?

```
+31 123456789
0123456789
0123 456 789
0 123 456 789
```

I need to incorporate it into:

```
If ($MobilePhone.ToString() -match '0(?<CountryCode>\d)\s+(?<Number>.........)')
{ "+31 $($Matches['CountryCode']) $($Matches['Number'])" }
Else
{ $MobilePhone.ToString() }
```

Comment: Why this question is marked down or get penalized?

Comment: I have not voted here, but I imagine people thought that too little effort was made, especially since you are a Senior Systems Engineer. (You added a follow-up question to Toby below, which also appeared to demonstrate no prior work - readers generally will try to encourage you to exhaust options on your side first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
$regex = "^([\+|0-9 ][ 0-9.]{1,12})$"
$number = "+31 123456789"

if($number -match $regex){
    Write-Host "It matches" -ForegroundColor Green
}else{
    Write-Host "Invalid number" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
"+31 123456789" -match '^\+\d{2}\s\d{9}$'
"0123456789" -match '^\d{10}$'
"0123 456 789" -match '^\d{4}(\s\d+){2}$'
"0 123 456 789" -match '^\d(\s\d{3}){3}$'
```

Related to: [Modifying PowerShell to display phone number in International format without changing the AD Attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514044/modifying-powershell-to-display-phone-number-in-international-format-without-cha/53514915#53514915)

Comment: Yes, it is related Toby.

Comment: I wanted to capture the four patterns, so how is that possible?

Comment: I would use `switch -regex` to capture those patterns. have a look at: https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2018-01-12-Powershell-switch-statement/